# Exclude loading <embed> item during loading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loading

I'm designing a website for a friend of mine which uses a lot of big images, therefore I created a loading overlay whilst everything loads in the background. However, there is also background music on the page under the form of an < embed >. The problem is, as soon as I added the < embed > the loading page doesn't pass 99% until the browser has fully loaded the background music.

Here's my loading page code:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
    show();
});

function show() {
    $(&#39;#loading&#39;).fadeOut();
    $(&#39;#container&#39;).fadeIn();
};
</script>
```

Here is my background music code:

```
<embed autoplay='true' height='1' loop='TRUE' src='background.mp3' width='1'/>
```

The music code delays the disappearance of the loading page whether it's in our outside of #loading, #container, < body >. Wherever I place it in the HTML, it delays the loading overlay.

I would like the music to start during the loading overlay and continue once the page is loaded, but the problem is my javascript is picking it up and therefore not hiding the loading page until it has loaded the music.

I would be grateful if somebody could come up with the coding as I'm not very good with javascript.

Thanks for your help in advance!

**Note:** My music file is 10Mb

Answer (score 2):

Try

HTML

```
<embed autoplay='true' height='1' loop='TRUE' src='' width='1'/>
```

js

```
$(window).load(function() {
    show();
    $('embed').attr('src','background.mp3');
});
```

---

Adding `src` after the page is loaded.

Comment: This does allow the loading page to go away and loads properly, however, the effect I'm looking for is to have the music and the page load simultaneously without the music interrupting the loading page. The music only starts playing a few seconds after the loading page has gone.

Comment: My music file is 10Mb

Comment: @Pixxies Bad idea i will take very much time to load /